# Direct image of a set

Tags: real-analysis

for a function definded on $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f((x,y))=x-9$

i want to find $f(A)$ where $$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, (x-1)^2+(y+1)^2<1\}$$

How to do ?

Can i say that $$f(A)=]1-\sqrt{1-(y+1)^2}, 1+\sqrt{1-(y+1)^2}[$$ with $-2<y<0$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: if $(x,y) \in A$, then $-2<x<0$ hence $-11 <f(x,y)<-9$.

Comment: one tell me that i can just say that $f(A)=\{x-9, (x-1)^2<1\}$ then $f(A)=]-9,-7[$ is it correct ? it is not the same with your result

Comment: i edited my message @Fred

Comment: Please, why we don't say that $f(A)=]1-\sqrt{1-(y+1)^2}, 1+\sqrt{1-(y+1)^2}[$ with  $-2<y<0$